# output of merged files with different length using common column -- prints additional column

Tags: linux

I manage to merge two files of different length with common columns (mid) but the output is not the desired one.

IT will be great if you can check the code that i used.

file 1

```
mid A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  A6
18  we  gf  32  23  45  89
19  ew  fg  33  24  46  90
21  ew  fg  35  26  48  92
```

file 2

```
mid B1  B2  B3  B4
18  r40 1   103 NA
19  r41 1   104 NA
20  r42 1   105 NA
21  r43 1   106 NA
```

used code:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next} ($1) in a{print $0, a[$1]}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

actual output:

```
mid     B1      B2      B3      B4 **mid**  A1      A2      A3      A4      A5      A6
18      r40     1       103     NA 18   we      gf      32      23      45      89
19      r41     1       104     NA 19   ew      fg      33      24      46      90
21      r43     1       106     NA 21   ew      fg      35      26      48      92
```

while the desired output is:without the column **MID**

```
mid     B1      B2      B3      B4    A1      A2      A3      A4      A5      A6
18      r40     1       103     NA    we      gf      32      23      45      89
19      r41     1       104     NA    ew      fg      33      24      46      90
21      r43     1       106     NA    ew      fg      35      26      48      92
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `join`: http://linux.die.net/man/1/join

```
join -j1 file2 file1
```

Prints

```
mid B1 B2 B3 B4 A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6
18 r40 1 103 NA we gf 32 23 45 89
19 r41 1 104 NA ew fg 33 24 46 90
21 r43 1 106 NA ew fg 35 26 48 92
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> a[$1]=$0
```

This captures the entire input line, including the `mid` column.  If you don't want that, don't do that.

```
line=$0; sub(/^[^ \t]+[ \t]+/, "", line); a[$1]=line
```